# Shape Memory Metal framed sail

Tags: arduino, batteries, current, memory, model

I am working on a costume prop that utilizes a triangular cut sheet of emergency blanket spined with a single 12" long, .04" dia piece of nitinol wire that has a transistion temp of 115deg F. My plan is to have this mounted on my wrist between two sleeves. When I hit a button the wire is intended to warm up unwrap like a sail and extend to its full length. If anyone has ever seen the show Fullmetal alchemist then you know exactly what it is Im looking to accomplish.
So heres where I need some help. the wire I have is too thick I guess for a simple 9v to cause it to extend at all. I am at less than a week to get this finished and the reason for the wire method has to do with space, concealment/surprise and safety for those around me. I am looking for anyone who might have good experience working with batteries and nitinol wire that might be able to assist me with just finding a wire/method that would be easy and quick to accomplish. I have been on many youtube sites and the all show things working but little to no explination or they use flexinol which does the opposite of what I need it curves when charged. Can anyone help?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not an electronic design question.

Comment: @LeonHeller - utterly untrue.  The poster is trying to design an electronic heating device.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is supposed to be an engineering SE, so let's do some calculations.

Nitinol has a resistivity of 76\$\mu\Omega\$-cm at room temperature (higher when hot). So the resistance of that wire should be \$\rho L/A\$.

A = \$\pi r^2\$ = 0.0081cm\$^2\$.

L = 30.5cm

So R ~= 0.29\$\Omega\$

That's fairly low. For, say 20W into the wire.. we'd need about 8A, which is 2.3V.

Let's say we use fresh alkaline AA cells which have a short circuit current of about 4-5A, so their Thevenin equivalent is a 1.5 source with 0.33 ohms in series. Three parallel strings of three AA cells (9 cells total) would yield a 4.5V supply with 0.33 ohms internal resistance (well matched for maximum power transfer).

Current would be about 7.3A, which is pretty close to our desired 20W. If it's not enough, four strings of four (16 cells total) would give 25 or 30W.

Comment: Nice... but the diameter is 0.04" = 1mm, pi * r^2 ~ 0.008cm^2, and the length is 12" = 30 cm.  I got ~ 0.28 ohms.  (unless I made a mistake too  :^)

Comment: How did 12 inches become 4.72 cm?

Comment: @DaveTweed There appears to have been a malfunction somewhere between the keyboard and the chair.

Answer (score 1):

A 9v battery is a poor choice for this application.

Your wire will have quite low resistance, and require a fairly high current to heat to actuating temperature.

Therefore, you do not want a high voltage, low current supply like a 9v "transistor" battery, as it will not only be quickly depleted, but will have a very high internal losses which may prevent you from ever delivering the desired current to heat the shape-memory wire.

Rather, you want a low-voltage high-current supply, such as one-or more "D" cells (you can experimentally try other sizes - it's possible some quality "AA" cells might work briefly)

If you know the diameter and composition or part number of your wire you can look up its resistance in ohms per unit length and begin to calculate what the current draw will be for a given battery voltage - looking up data on the cell(s) comprising the battery, you can then also figure out how much of your power will be wasted in losses in the cell itself.

Comment: some great advice thanks I'll look into it starting tomorrow. I should have known that 9v batteries didn't necessarily have the highest current.